# why using dialog and putextra doesn't work

Tags: java, android

My problem here, why `dialog.putExtra` doesn't work?

My code:

```
dialog.putExtra();
```

Can `putExtra` be added to the `dialog`?

maybe someone here can help my problem

Answer (score 0):

putExtra is not appropriate for Dialog. It is a component of Intent. You Can't use putExtra to Dialog class.

If you share what you really want to do, I hope I can further help you.

Comment: Oh like that, then what is the substitute for putExtra in the dialog?

Comment: You can use TextView in Dialog and use setText to set value to it.

Comment: I still haven't come up with an idea until now or I'm too stupid not to know how to get data like using intent.putExtra using dialogs

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `DialogFragment`, you can pass a bundle and set arguments to `DialogFragment` and get it back in your `DialogFragment`. You will also get lifecycle callbacks associated to it.

Or if you want to use `Dialog` only, you will have to set it as recommended by @K M Rejowan Ahmmed